# How to present a list of matching strings in string array?

Tags: java

Imagine a list of foods. The user searches for a food and is presented with a list of all foods which match this.

Example, user search 'apple', program returns 'red apple', 'green apple', etc.

```
for (int i = 0; ; i++) {
     if (foodNames[i].contains(searchTerm){
         foodChoice1 = foodName[i];
         break;
         // then print food name
     }
}
```

How would this be extended to show more than one food name from the list? The code was just mocked up on the spot, likely doesn't work, just to show an example.

Comment: use a `List` (an `ArrayList` for example)

Comment: That seems like it should work for the question you are asking

Comment: If there is no matching you will get a [ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html)

Comment: Depends how you want to output the matches, really. If you're not really bothered about what the output looks like you could just not `break;` the first time you find a match, and instead iterate through the full collection, printing out each match.

Answer (score 2):

What about using a `Set<String>` to store the results and comparing to lower case?

```
String[] foods = {
    "Red apple", "Green APPLE", "Apple pie", 
    "Lobster Thermidor Sausage and SPAM"
};
String query = "apple";
String queryTLC = query.toLowerCase();
// sorting result set lexicographically
Set<String> results = new TreeSet<String>();
for (String food: foods) {
    if (food.toLowerCase().contains(queryTLC)) {
        results.add(food);
    }
}
System.out.println(results);
```

**Output**

```
[Apple pie, Green APPLE, Red apple]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
List<String> matchingFood = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < foodNames.length; i++) {
    if (foodNames[i].contains(searchTerm)
    {
         matchingFood.add(foodName[i]);
    }
}
System.out.println("Food matching '" + searchTerm + "' :");
for (String f : matchingFood)
{
    system.out.prinln(f);
}
```

Comment: You can spare time (and lines of output) by printing the list directly : `System.out.println(matchingFood)`

Comment: Yes, it was for the clarity of the answer

Answer (score -1):

you can simply use this:

```
String[] strArray = {"green apple", "red apple", "yellow apple"};
for (String s : strArray)
    if (s.contains("apple"))
        System.out.println(s);
```